# wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable) is not waiting for the defined time

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Using Using Selenium WebDriver with Java and I want to click on an element that is present on the page and is visible, but is grayed out, i.e., element is present on the page but the same is not intractable.

So, I am using `ExplicitWebDriverWait` to wait until that element is clickable and for that I am using below line of code. But the same is not working. Driver is not waiting for the element to become intractable. It is throwing exception, "`is not clickable at point (415, 765). Other element would receive the click:`".

Now,if I am using `static wait` instead of this `Explicit Waint`, I am able to click on the element.

***Code which I have written:***

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@name='mobile']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@name='mobile']")));
newNum.click();
```

***Script Log:***

```
Trying to locate: By.xpath: //*[@name='mobile']
Located element:By.xpath: //*[@name='mobile']
Trying to locate: By.xpath: //*[@name='mobile']
Located element:By.xpath: //*[@name='mobile']
Trying to locate: By.xpath: //*[@name='mobile']
Located element:By.xpath: //*[@name='mobile']
Trying to click on:[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (7686dd92e2bb577696qa2e1aa13effd6)] -> xpath: //*[@name='mobile']]
Exception occured:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <input id="abc-radiobox-2032-inputEl" data-ref="inputEl" type="text" role="combobox" size="1" name="mobile" placeholder="- select option -" readonly="readonly" class="dummyclass" autocomplete="off" componentid="gwc-combobox-2032"> is not clickable at point (415, 765). Other element would receive the click: <div class="anotherclass" role="status" id="loadmask-1985" tabindex="0" componentid="loadmask-1985" style="">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e1234de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Comment: You did not add the line of code whare you're waiting.

Comment: Have added the line of code as well as the script log now

Comment: "...but is grayed out" The message "other element would recieve the click" usualy means there is a frame needed to switch driver to. But this does not change the fact, your target element still grayed out - not interactible. Execute your test scenario manualy first, to take a closer look what's going on in DOM.

Comment: Manual execution is done, and there is no frame involved here.
And also, as I mentioned the same is working when I am using static wait(Thread.sleep), but not with explicit Wait.

Comment: More important is, what other element would recieve the click. Post more of the exception (or complete exception).

Comment: @pburgr This is the complete exception which I am getting till the termination of my application.  Before this, there are just success logs for other elements not related to this.

Comment: There is a div with id "loadmask-1985" which overlays target element.

Comment: Yes that overlay element(id=loadmask-1985) gets loaded first, that's why I have used explicit wait. But the  script is not waiting for that underlying element to be clickable.It's just throwing exception straight away.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error you are getting:

> Exception: **is not clickable at point (415, 765). Other element would receive the click:**

Seems like driver is not able to even find the particular element, so its not waiting until it becomes clickable. Mostly whenever this type of error occurs, we can use JavaScript Clicks instead of using wait or any other types of clicks.

**Try the below code:** make sure element locator's value should be good enough to locate the element uniquely:

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='mobile']"));
 JavascriptExecutor Js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 Js.executeScript("arguments[0].clicks();", element)`

This code always works for me. Sometimes I need to insert `scrollIntoView()` method to scroll the page to the element to perform action on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait, until the element is visible. And then need to check whether element is in enable state(clickable state) or not. After that only, you have to perform the click operation.

Steps

1.Create Firefox browser session

2.Navigate to the page as per you requirement

3.Wait, until the web element (//*[@name='mobile']) is visible [wait for approximately 15 seconds]

[What is web element ? Ans : Whatever the action you are going to perform with this element. This element may be a button , link, icon, text field, etc..]

4.Now check the element, it is in clickable state(enable state) or not

5.If it is in clickable state(enable state), then perform the click operation.

```
public void test_01_ButtonClick()
{
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("www.hlo.com");            

//Here will check element is visible or not 
waitForElementInDOM(driver, "//*[@name='mobile']", 15); 

//Here will check element is enable or not
boolean enable = elementIsEnable(driver, "//*[@name='mobile']");    
if(enable)
{
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='mobile']")).click();
}
else
{
System.out.println("Element not visible. Please increase your waiting time");
}
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void waitForElementInDOM(WebDriver driver,String elementIdentifier, long 
timeOutInSeconds) 
{       
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds );
try
{           
//this will wait for element to be visible for 15 seconds        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
(By.xpath(elementIdentifier))); 
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e)
{           
e.printStackTrace();
}           
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public boolean elementIsEnable(WebDriver driver, String elementIdentifier)
{
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("elementIdentifier"));
if(element.isEnabled())
{
return true;
}
else 
{
return false;
}       
}
```